# XAMPP services (PhpMyAdmin and Apache ) not working when add Xdebug

Tags: xampp, xdebug

When I add Xdebug to the php.ini file, the Apache and PhpMyAdmin services are no longer available through the browser.

NOTE:

- XAMPP version: last version (PHP 8.0.11)
- Xdebug version : last version 3.*

**php.ini :**

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
```

Comment: *"Xdebug version : last version 3.*"* Please state EXACT version. If it's 3.1.0 then downgrade to 3.0.4 for the moment -- looks like TS build of Xdebug has some issues on Windows (Apache use TS builds of PHP) -- see https://stackoverflow.com/q/69449103/783119 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/69506768/783119

Comment: But then -- just having Xdebug should not affect normal code execution (worked for those ppl)... Anyway -- try 3.0.x build for now.

Comment: FWIW, Xdebug 3.1.1 has now been released, which should fix this problem too.